# как сделать необычное закругление у блока?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать такое закругление при помощи boredr-radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#x{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
background: black;
border: 20px solid black;
}
#x:after{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-radius: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 400%;
top: -150%; left: 0;
background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'></div>
```

но это такое себе... попробуйте clip-path, svg или даже radial-gradient на фоне.